# Grails - why is setDateCreated invoked multiple times?

Tags: grails, timestamp, grails-orm

I have this really simple Grails entity:

```
package timestamp.fail

class Post {

String title
String body
Date dateCreated

static constraints = {
    title(blank: false)
    body(blank: false)
}

void setDateCreated(Date d){
    dateCreated = d

    if(dateCreated){
        System.out.println(" dateCreated OK!!! ")
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(" dateCreated null =/ ")
    }
}
}
```

I've been doing some debugging over it and noticed setDateCreated is invoked multiple times when I save the instance. One odd thing I noticed is that, when saving an instance from BootStrap.groovy, the first setDateCreated is invoked, the "d" param is null, although the following 2 times it's invoked properly.

Why is it called so many times? Is there some kind of lifecycle behind it? Which execution should I rely on to do some logic with the creation date? Should I not rely on this date for doing something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Comments on http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9805 might help understand some aspects.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of [autoTimestemp](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/autoTimestamp.html) grails feature.